# Error with Fibonacci sequence in python

Tags: python

Edit - All fixed thank you

```
fib=[0,1]
for i in range(0,700):
    fib.append(fib[len(fib)-2]+fib[len(fib)-1])
    print(fib[len(fib)-1])
print('Do you want a range of numbers or single?')
answer=input()
if answer=='single':
    print('Which number?')
    number=int(input())
    fib[number]
elif answer=='range':
    print('From:')
    firstNumber=int(input())
    print('To:')
    secondNumber=int(input())
    fib[firstNumber:secondNumber]
```

I have been trying to create a Fibonacci sequence in python which allows you to choose either which number to show or what range of numbers to show (script above). However when i run the script it runs fine at the start, i get to the part when you enter the number you want (either a single number, or the to and from numbers) but when i do nothing happens and the script ends. I am very new to python (coming from html and css, and i CBA right now to code this in HTML xD). Could anyone help me?

Comment: put the code in the question not an image

Comment: You seem to think that you put the for-loop in your code in a function. Put your for-loop in a function.

Comment: You obviously know how `print` works, why don't you use it?

Comment: you do not `print` out the result of `fib[number]` or `fib[firstNumber:secondNumber]` so it doesn't get displayed, instead it just gets calculated and then thrown out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fib=[0,1]
for i in range(0,700):
    fib.append(fib[len(fib)-2]+fib[len(fib)-1])
    print(fib[len(fib)-1])
answer=input('Do you want a range of numbers or single?')
if answer=='single':
    number=int(input('Which number?[index]: '))
    print(fib[number])
elif answer=='range':
    firstNumber=int(input('From[index]: '))
    secondNumber=int(input('To[index]: '))
    print(fib[firstNumber:secondNumber])
else:
   print('Error')
```

Maybe this will work for you

Comment: Not sure if he's using Python 2 or 3, but it looks like he's using 3, so those `print`s will need parens and `raw_input` can be just `input`.